# Select the nearest DOM element with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How to access the div with specific class that is on the same level of DOM using jQuery?
I've tried .closest() but it doesn't find the element.

For example:

```
<!-- foreach loop starts { -->
<fieldset>
    <legend>Values</legend>
    <div class="characteristic-values">          
        <!-- many divs inside -->
    </div>
    <input type="button" class="add-charactersitic-value" value="Add Value" />
</fieldset>
<!-- } foreach loop ends -->
```

And JavaScript that tries to access the "charactersitic-values" but without success:

```
<script>
$(".add-charactersitic-value").live("click", function () {
    var addButton = $(this);

    // How to access the specified div from "addButton" variable?       
    // This doesn't work:
    //addButton.closest(".characteristic-values").append("<b>somedata</b>");    
});
</script>
```

How to access the "characteristic-values" in this case?

Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
.prev('.characteristic-values');
```

`.prev` selects previous ***siblings***.  `.closest` selects ***parents*** (and the current item itself)

If the item is not the immediate previous sibling, this won't work (as `.prev` only selects that one element).  You can do either of these instead:

```
.prevAll('.characteristic-values');
.parent().find('.characteristic-values');
```

Comment: Or `.prevAll('.characteristic-values:first')`

Comment: Thanks, .prev() - worked fine. Will use .prevAll("class:pseudo") if it will be needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".add-charactersitic-value").prev(".characteristic-values");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UUdXk/

Comment: This may not work, as add-charactersitic-value class is applied to many divs in the loop