# jQuery closest li with a class doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have menu (list of categories), level-0  li has class ".cat_cat_h", level-1 .cat_par_c"

HTML:

```
<ul class="text-links">
        <li class="cat_cat_h level-0"><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li class="cat_cat_h level-0"><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
        <li class="cat_cat_h level-0 active"><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
        <li class="cat_par_c level-1" style="display: none;"><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
        <li class="cat_par_c level-1" style="display: none;"><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
        <li class="cat_par_c level-1" style="display: none;"><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>  
        <li class="cat_cat_h level-0"><a href="#">Item 7</a></li>
        <li class="cat_cat_h level-0"><a href="#">Item 8</a></li>
        <li class="cat_cat_h level-0"><a href="#">Item 9</a></li>
        <li class="cat_cat_h level-0"><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
        <li class="cat_par_c level-1" style="display: none;"><a href="#">Item 7</a></li>  
        <li class="cat_par_c level-1" style="display: none;"><a href="#">Item 8</a></li>  
        <li class="cat_par_c level-1" style="display: none;"><a href="#">Item 9</a></li>  
</ul>
```

I would like to show() only level-1 elements that go right after .level-0.active (item 4, item 5, item 6).

**UPDATE**

Final solution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$( ".level-0.active" ).nextUntil( ".level-0" ).show();
});
```

Comment: Who knows? I can't see the DOM you're selecting. I don't know if that class exists.

Comment: post your html code and a fiddle please so we can help you

Comment: It should be noted that closest() starts with the current element, but it's impossible to tell what the issue is here ?

Comment: Added HTML.  Im trying to show only level-1 elements related to the .level-0.active class.

Comment: The issue is that you need to read [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/closest) for `.closest()`

Comment: If the `.level-1` elements always come after the `.level-0.active` element, then you can simplify with a single selector: `$(".level-0.active ~ .level-1").show()`. Otherwise, read jQuery's documentation on Traversing.

Comment: Why do you keep changing the code in your question?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Description: For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.*

[Source](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

That means the `closest()` function works in one direction. if you want to go to the parent `<ul>` and the  back to another `<li>` you have to call the `parent()` function first, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".cat_cat_h").parent('ul').find(".cat_par_c").show();
});
```

**edit after your edit:**

If you want the previous and the next element of you selected element try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $( ".level-0.active" ).prev().show();
   $( ".level-0.active" ).next().show();
});
```

Comment: Im trying to show only level-1 elements related to the .level-0.active class. So how do I select li with .active class first?

Comment: @Tim: If that was your issue, why didn't you ask about it? If you want to target `.level-1` classes relative to `.level-0.active`, don't  you think that you would maybe need to use those selectors?

Comment: $(".cat_cat_h.active").parent('ul').find(".cat_par_c").show();  still doesn't work. It shows/hides all elements, not the closest to ".active" only.

Comment: [something like this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476762/select-the-nearest-dom-element-with-jquery)

Comment: @Tim: All the `.cat_par_c` elements are `.level-1` and are in the same `UL` container as the `.active` one. So what's the problem? You said you want to target `.level-1` elements, right?

Comment: @cookiemonster sorry If explained it wrong.

What I'm trying to do is hide only level-1 elements which are close to level-0.active element, but not all level-1 elements within this UL.

Comment: @Tim: It would be good to explain what you mean by "close". Do you mean consecutive `.level-1` elements that are adjacent to the `.level-0.active` element?

Comment: @cookiemonster yes, for example in my HTML code ".level-0 active" next to it are three level-1 items (Item 4, Item 5, Item6). I want to target only them.

Comment: It's all yours Nano. ;-)

Comment: @Nano thank you for your help! :)  next() selects only one element though, would it be possible to select all level-1 elements that go after level-0.active, until next non-active level-0 ?

Comment: @Nano found out I could use nextUntil().  Thank you for your help once again.

Answer (score 1):

To be responsive to Paulchenkiller, I will amplify my answer.

Fluency in any language, spoken (English, Spanish, Italian, French, German, etc) or written (html, css, javascript, c++, pascal, basic, etc) requires the ability to express a certain concept, idea or task in a variety of different ways.

I will attempt to do so with this particular issue in as many ways that this particular noob can think of.

1. jQuery selectors - this has been nicely expounded on above, and the only comment I might make is  the trivial downside in the use of jQuery in terms of its load time (microseconds to milliseconds), and perhaps slightly longer to run than native js (microseconds).
2. CSS classes - One way to handle this is the use of additional css classes - adding a class, say "li456" that is an "empty" class in the sense that it contains no CSS styling, and is only used to identify a particular line or lines of code. Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Qz48m/1/) as an example. It's a bit inefficient in the sense that it can be difficult to follow the code with so many classes attached to a line of html, and needing to look up an additional class in the  section or even an attached style sheet.

> ```
>       $(".li456").show();
> ```

1. CSS ids - Even more burdensome, since you can only use an id once on a page, and in this particular case, therefore need three ids. The same applies to ids as to classes, only worse, you have to look up three times the number of ids as classes - since one class can be associated with multiple html lines on a given page. Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Qz48m/2/) that shows an example of the use of ids .

> ```
>   $("#li4, #li5, #li6").show();
> ```

1. A variant of CSS is the concept of pseudo classes which are beautifully explained by the experts at CSS-Tricks where they have a nice review of these flexible and powerful methods (http://css-tricks.com/pseudo-class-selectors/). The :lt(x) selects the first x elements of type. Here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Qz48m/). The :lt() pseudo class is particular to jquery and not a part of the CSS standard.

> ```
> $(".text-links .cat_par_c:lt(3)").show();
> ```

1. Pure javascript is also a possibility, but in this particular case you would have to add an id to the three elements in question. Here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Qz48m/3/).

> document.getElementById('li4').style.display='block';
>   document.getElementById('li5').style.display='block';
>   document.getElementById('li6').style.display='block';

1. Pure javascript can be used to select on the class name, and return an array that can be parsed by [n]. This [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Qz48m/4/) shows an example of a brute-force method. This [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Qz48m/5/) uses a for loop to go through three elements.

> document.getElementsByClassName('cat_par_c')[n].style.display='block';

1. Then we move to "display" which can be handled with jQuery .show, .css('display', 'block') and javascript .style.display='block'. This [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Qz48m/7/) demonstrates these methods.

> ```
> $('.cat_par_c:eq(0)').show();
> $('.cat_par_c:eq(1)').css('display', 'block');
> document.getElementsByClassName('cat_par_c')[2].style.display='block';
> ```

1. And I'll bet there are many more ways...

Comment: Take a look at [answer]

Comment: And can you provide me details on what is wrong with my answer?

Comment: You just post Code, but you should explain what you did and why you did it. SO is a place for helping people understanding problems.

Comment: Let's see - I did it for a "different approach" (as stated in my answer) - you can spend time using .parent/.child/.nearest/.prev/.next or you can just use a simpler pseudo class. I'll bet there are many other ways to do this that I don't know about. Anyone who posts here should know a little about pseudo classes, so they don't need explanation.

Comment: Well... but what about people who search for a similar question, going to this post and just dont understand what you answered? It isn't a given that people know what pseudo classes are. People who are new to js, html, css,... need to learn that. so its up to you to give them a short summary of what you did and how it (might) work. The point is, that you want to teach other people. you just dont want to give them an answer they can copy in their code and they have no idea what that code snipped does.